# Cannot locate Old British Patent

Tags: british

I can find references to 2 old British patents, but cannot locate them anywhere online.  Could anyone assist?

Many Thanks.

Patents:

First is 25306/51.  a relevant date appears to be 30Oct1951.

Second is 7523/52

The applicant may be Francis or Frank Whitehead.  The assignee may be Milner Ltd; or Chatwood Milner Ltd. They relate to combination locks.

Comment: Those numbers seem to be application numbers not patent numbers. Do you have any other numbers? A GB patent number in 1951 would be in the 600,000 to 750,000 range.

Comment: I can't find any Francis or Frank Whiteheads among British patents. Can you relate where you are getting the names of inventor, assignee and document numbers?

Comment: The date and numbers were not helpful in finding any documents. Are you confident there are two GB patents?

Answer (score 1):

There is a U.S. patent *Combination lock* [US 276,6606](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2766606A) with inventor Frank Whitehead assigned to Milner Safe Co Ltd.

It claims priority from a British application GB1428952A filed June 6, 1952. That application resulted in [GB761432](https://patents.google.com/patent/GB761432A/) *Improvements in or relating to locks*

It doesn’t look like any of the numbers or dates in the question are related to those documents.

From the GB provisional application -

[image]